# Microsoft One Drive solution for Files and Folders - Around 300 Systems

Tags: backup, onedrive

I need Files and Folders backup of 300 Windows 8+ System. I opted One Drive Solution. So do i need to buy 300 License of One Drive for Business or Can i buy 1 license and can create and share 300 folders for each person?

In any of the option, the user can upload data to their space but admin can see all the folders.

Comment: Please, clarify negative vote reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can map your OneDrive as a shared Drive on each machine. But in this case all data can be overlooked by administrator. Yes, like you said.

Have a look at OneDrive For Business probably. They have a licensing model per user. From security perspective this is much better for you.

Answer (score 0):

A third-party tool e.g.Cloudberry MBS may be a solution in your case.It works rather well with any number of machines. What I like more is that the tool is intergrated with leading cloud storages like Amazon, Google, Openstack etc.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, at an enterprise level, we should not consider onedrive as cloud storage as it is a kind of online file sync service.
So, you should go for a backup software to manage your 300+ system's backup and restorations.
The main point of backing up is to preserve data the backup solution has to be bullet-proof. Thus, a backup solution has to be able to encrypt backups and securely transfer data over the network.
Veeam, Microsoft DPM and other EMC products can be an option but it totally depends upon the backup requirements.
you need software which can backup your data to any preferred storage like NAS and Cloud. You can try Cloudberry Backup Software as it provides "Cloud to Cloud", "Cloud to Local" and "Local to Cloud"